# how do I configure my keyboard to write acute accents?

Tags: keyboard

How do I configure on  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the keyboard to write acute accents?

Comment: Via `Shift-´` and `A`, e.g.?

Comment: it gives back 'a

Comment: maybe I should check the layout on the system settings

Comment: If one of the below answers helped, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

### Configuration

Go into Ubuntu's system settings and then click "Keyboard", in the shortcuts tab there's a section called typing so open that up. Once your in typing enable "`Compose key`" and assign it to whatever you would like. (Personally I use `rAlt`) After thats enabled hold down your `compose key` press the english key first then the tilde.

### Examples

> 'compose key' + a + ' = á

> 'compose key' + a + ` = à

Comment: I oppened Keyboard and there were 2 tabs, one named shortcuts other named typping. I went on the Shortcut  tab but there I found no typing section. On the other tab, the typing tab one just finds Repeat keys and cursor Blinking... any ideas?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey try using this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a QWERTY keyboard, add the following lay-out: `English, US, Alternative International` and it'll do `à` by pressing <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>, `ç` by pressing <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd>, ...

Comment: @Conrado: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!